# Flutter Dismissible Widget re shows the widget after dismissing

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-widget, dismissible

i am trying to make a list in which its tiles can be deleted  when dragged so i used the Dismissible widget and everything is working as i wanted, however when dragging the tile to dismiss it the tile re shows for a few moment and disappear, a demo of what i mean is shown in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fn9KkKrMZLA&feature=share)

```
FutureBuilder(
        future: getMyFavData(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.data == null)
            return Container(
                child: Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
            )));
          else
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  var monthOfProductList =
                      snapshot.data.elementAt(index)['date'].toDate().month;
                  var monthNow = DateTime.now().month;
                  bool newItem = false;
                  if (monthNow - monthOfProductList == 0) {
                    newItem = true;
                  }
                  return Dismissible(
                    key: UniqueKey(),
                    onDismissed: (direction) async  {
                      if (direction == DismissDirection.startToEnd) {

                        await deleteFromDataBase(
                            snapshot.data.elementAt(index).documentID);

                        setState(() {
                          snapshot.data.remove(index);
                        });

                      }
                    },
                    background: Container(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Icon(
                            Icons.delete_forever,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            size: 100,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    direction: DismissDirection.startToEnd,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {

                        Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => ProductFullScreenView(
                                      productInfo: snapshot.data.elementAt(index),
                                    )));
                      },
                      child: ProductListCardVerticalFavorite(),
                    ),
                  );
                });
        });
```

i am not sure where the problem is, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used `FutureBuilder` to fetch a list of data and on the `onDismissed` you remove it.

When you dismiss an item, the widget that holds it will rebuild again so you don't need to call the `setState`.

Also when you call a remove function(`deleteFromDataBase`), that's going to remove some real saved data so you don't need to remove it from data you fetched because here when an item is removed a function will be called to delete it from real saved data too and the widget will be rebuilt and another call(`getMyFavData()`) would occur on saved data to fetch them but this time the result is all of the previous one without the removed item.

I made a simple example out of your code and made a fake future call:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(Home());
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  List<String> lst = [
    '1',
    '2',
    '4',
    '5',
    '6',
    '7',
    '8',
    '9',
    '10',
    '11',
  ];
  Future<List<String>> getMyFavData() async {
    return Future.value(lst);
  }

  Future<void> deleteFromDataBase(int index) async {
    Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500)).then((_) {
      lst.removeAt(index);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: FutureBuilder(
            future: getMyFavData(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.data == null)
                return Container(
                  child: Center(
                    child:
                        CircularProgressIndicator(backgroundColor: Colors.red),
                  ),
                );
              else
                return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Dismissible(
                          key: UniqueKey(),
                          onDismissed: (direction) async {
                            if (direction == DismissDirection.startToEnd) {
                              await deleteFromDataBase(index);
                            }
                          },
                          background: Container(
                            color: Colors.red,
                            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.delete_forever,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                          direction: DismissDirection.startToEnd,
                          child: Container(
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                            child: Text(lst[index]),
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                          ));
                    });
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, the problem i had with your code is  that when my list is clicked it will navigate to the full screen of the product, however when going back from the fullscreen to the favorite by the back button the dissmisable widget will show an error that says "A dismissed Dismissible widget is still part of the tree." i solved it by calling setState() before navigating to the full screen when pressed.

Comment: You're welcome, I made a navigation and I didn't get any error, if you like you can  open a new question or add more info to this one about data and the functions, I'll be glad to help.

Comment: its all good now and if its working i would rather not to touch it hahahaha thanks again

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid assign a future in the build method. Save an instance in the initState, because every time your build the tree rebuilt the future is called again.

```
Future myCachedFuture;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    myCachedFuture = getMyFavData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(future: myCachedFuture,)
  }
```

Comment: i will start using this, Thanks a lot gauris